# How to add action in HTML depending on two option combination?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How to add condition like this:

> If customer  chose Japan as a pickup option and England as a dropoff option, page sends him on page with prices of that destination and for some other input there is exactly one output for exact chosen destination and pickup place.

```html
<div class="advanced-search color" id="booking">
  <div class="wrap">
    <form role="form" action="index.html" method="get">
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="f-row">
        <div class="form-group select one-third">
          <label>Pick up location</label>
          <select id="pickup1" name="p1">
            <option value="">Select pickup location</option>
            <optgroup label="Asia">
              <option value="1">China</option>
              <option value="2">Japan</option</optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group select one-third">
          <label>Drop off location</label>
          <select id="dropoff1" name="d1">
            <option value="">Select drop-off location</option>
            <optgroup label="Europe">
              <option value="3">England</option>
              <option value="4">Spain</option</optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group right">
          <center>
            <label>Check for informations</label>
          </center>
          <button type="submit" class="btn large black">Find a transfer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- //Row -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a server issue. Submit the form and show the page you need. Alternatively Ajax in the correct combination using the selected values

Comment: This is really vague.  What backend language are you using?  Where/how is the pricing information stored?  As is, clicking the submit button will send the user to `index.html`, with the values in the `GET` parameters.

Comment: If some of you guys could write a short javascript for my issue i would be grateful. Sort of something like this: "If pickup is option number 1 and dropoff is option nuber 3, open www.stackoverflow.com" I am beginner in HTML so i can't coraspodence with you easily with terms. I found this free template so i'm playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this,

```
$(#dropOffSelect).on('change',function(){
   var dropOffval = $(this).val();
   var pickUplocation = $('#pickUpselect').val();
//condition runs here 
   if(pickUplocation ==='Japan' && dropOffval === 'Europe'){
    // show the information for it
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple using jQuery. You send the values to the pricelist page via querystring in your url. On load of the pricelist page you get the values from the query string and filter based on it.
Now you'll have to work with the values in the list and not the text. You can match the values from a database or you can still use the country name as the value.

```
$(function() {
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
$('form').attr('action', 'pricelist?pickup=' + p1.val() + '&dropoff=' + d1.val());
$('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.location within your script no need to use action just add onclick="Myfunc()" event.

```
if(pickup == "japan" && dropoff == "england")
   window.location = "url";
```